# Custom Authorization Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I am implementing a CustomAuthorizeAttribute. I need to get the name of the action being executed. How can i get the name of current action name getting executed in the AuthorizeCore function which i am overriding ?

Comment: Why do you need the name of the action? One of the points of implementing a custom authorization attribute is so that it can be done independently of which action is being executed.

Comment: @Daniel you might want to create Authorization based on a action name convention. Altough this might be better achieved using some kind of IFilterProvider.

Comment: @Daniel, Hi, I want to map certain actions to a Role. Hence the requirement. I am basically mapping users to roles and roles to actions and i validate if the user has rights to execute an action based on his role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Action Name like this:

```
public class CustomAuthFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

If you want to inherit from the AuthorizationAttribute you'll need to override the OnAuthorization method.

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess i could also use var controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

Comment: You could. You're using magic string which is ALWAYS more error prone and I'm also sure what would happen when calling ChildActions from a view...

Comment: Magic strings !!  yes you are right. I will go with filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

Answer (score 5):

If you're using cache (or have plans to), then overriding `AuthorizeCore`, like Darin Dimitrov shows in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594726/authorize-current-user-against-controller-and-action-name-in-asp-net-mvc-3/5594783#5594783) is a much safer bet:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
    var controller = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    var action = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
    ...
}
```

The reason for this is documented in the [MVC source code](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68345#266447) itself:

**AuthorizeAttribute.cs** (lines 72-101)

```
public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
    if (filterContext == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }

    if (OutputCacheAttribute.IsChildActionCacheActive(filterContext)) {
        // If a child action cache block is active, we need to fail immediately, even if authorization
        // would have succeeded. The reason is that there's no way to hook a callback to rerun
        // authorization before the fragment is served from the cache, so we can't guarantee that this
        // filter will be re-run on subsequent requests.
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.AuthorizeAttribute_CannotUseWithinChildActionCache);
    }

    if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext)) {
        // ** IMPORTANT **
        // Since we're performing authorization at the action level, the authorization code runs
        // after the output caching module. In the worst case this could allow an authorized user
        // to cause the page to be cached, then an unauthorized user would later be served the
        // cached page. We work around this by telling proxies not to cache the sensitive page,
        // then we hook our custom authorization code into the caching mechanism so that we have
        // the final say on whether a page should be served from the cache.

        HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
        cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null /* data */);
    }
    else {
        HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Even if you didn't plan on using cache, those two magic strings seem a small price to pay for the peace of mind you get in return (and the potential headaches you save yourself.) If you still want to override `OnAuthorization` instead, you should at least make sure the request isn't cached. See [this post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1533590/3722925.aspx) by Levi for more context.