# Authorize current user against controller and action name in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I need to create a customized authorization in ASP.NET MVC 3. Inside the app, authorization is defined in 5 tables: users, groups, usergroups, rights, grouprights. A user can belong to several groups, and each right can be assigned to several groups too. Each controller action is assigned a RightID.

The built in authorization can't accomodate this setup, so I tried to create a customized AuthorizeAttribute. When overriding AuthorizeCore, I realized I don't have access to controller name and action name.

Can I somehow ask the router to parse the Request.RawUrl inside AuthorizeCore to get controller and action name? Or is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var routeData = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
    var controller = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    var action = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
    ...
}
```

Comment: So I DO have access to controller and action name :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **Action Filters** where you have access to all HttpContex.

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{

    #region Implementation of IAuthorizationFilter

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
              // ... implementation

              // filterContext.Controller is the controller
              // filterContext.RouteData is all the route data
```

Comment: I read somewhere that I should not implement my own authorization filter because of some problem with output cache. Not sure whether this is still a problem in MVC 3.

Comment: OnAuthorization can be cached/shared across requests and users, so this is not secure. Use AuthorizeCore instead.